# SAPUI5 List CustomListItem / Rerender Issue

Tags: list, binding, rendering, sapui5

I got a split-app, left Hand side a master list with persons. right-hand side a Detail page with info and RatingIndicator element. Two lists on the detail-page which are bound via associations: /Master/Detail/Rating.

Whenever I use the Rating Indicator, it seems like the page is rerendering, which makes everything slow at the end. I tried both, two-way binding and one-way-binding with manually updating the model. It still rerenders/reloads the page every time I use the Rating indicator.

Any idea someone?

SAPUI5 library is on Version 1.28.31.

Edit: In the meantime I reduced complexity (no lists within lists, thought this might be the issue, but it isnt), and still the issue occurs. Even now when I use the Rating indicator the whole Detail page reloads/rerenders. 
What can I do?

Before Clicking the Rating indicator:
[image: Before Clicking Rating Indicator]

Directly after cliking the Rating indicator, right-hand Detail page disappears and reappears withing seconds.
[image: right-hand Detail page disappears]

View:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="split.controller.Detail" xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:footerbar="sap.ushell.ui.footerbar"
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
<Page id="page" navButtonPress="onNavBack" showNavButton="{device>/system/phone}"
    title="{i18n>detailTitle}" busy="{detailView>/busy}"
    busyIndicatorDelay="{detailView>/delay}" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">

    <content>

        <List items="{ path: 'WorklistToDocument' }">

            <CustomListItem>

                <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin" }">
                    <Title titleStyle="H3" text="{Title}" }" />
                    <Text text="{Description}" }" />
                </VBox>

                <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                    <Text text="{Description}" />
                    <CheckBox selected="{NotApplicable}" select="onNACheckBoxSelect" />
                    <RatingIndicator value="{RatingValue}" maxValue="{MaxValue}" change="onRatingChanged" />
                    <Text
                        text="{ path: 'RatingValue', formatter: '.formatter.ratingText' }" />
                </VBox>

            </CustomListItem>
        </List>
    </content>

</Page>
```

Controller:

```
onRatingChanged: function(oEvent) {

    var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
    var oModel = this.getModel();
    var sPath = oSource.getBindingContext().sPath;
    var sCtxPath = sPath + "/RatingValue";
    var sCtxPathNA = sPath + "/NotApplicable";
    var iValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");

    oModel.setProperty(sCtxPath, iValue);
    oModel.setProperty(sCtxPathNA, false);

},
```

Comment: No solution, just a remark: It is not recommend to use complex controls as content of the CustomListItem. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.CustomListItem/about

Comment: got it, but I didnt see any options. All elements from the associations are dynamic, so I can't implement a fixed layout...

Answer (score 0):

Is this line

> var sCtxPath = sPath + "/RatingValue";

not leading to another "change" event trigger?
Additionally, is there a loop in your formatter that could cause a 'hang'?

And what about any events in your master with the same odata path?

Comment: I set a breakpoint in every master/Detail.Controller and None of them reacted. So I think it does not Trigger anything else. The line you mentioned is building the path which I use in setProperty, something like this WorklistSet(key ='1')/RatingValue --> this updates the value in the odata-model correctly , then rerendering occurs. btw I edited the main post, I reduced complexity massively, but the issue is still there.

Comment: I think it has to do with a change in your list. That change causes an update in your path or maybe router which then causes the re-rendering of your detail page. Perhaps it re-selects the item of the list. You could add an [event](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#fireSelectionChange) to your list to find out if that actually occurs. It still is no solution for your problem though.

Comment: I did set a console.log into every Controller method, even in ListSelector.js, nothing except my onRatingChanged-method gets triggered. also in debug mode, nothing else gets fired/triggered. What do you mean by add an Event to your list?

Comment: If you have a function in your controller called echo which does console.log you should add this function to all events that have to do with binding. I suggest to add all event to the [list](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html)

Comment: I also created my Project from scratch in WebIDE, for whatever reason within this Environment it seems to be working. As soon as I Transfer it (one-to-one, no changes) to my eclipse (even with the same Service) the browser does make this Rendering stuff...

Comment: That's weird. Could it be a library version difference?

Comment: Not sure got the latest 1.28.31 on my side... I also removed my onRatingChanged and switched to two-way-binding which has the same effect than manually updating the values with this method. Which ended in the same result. I don't get it...

Comment: I removed everything from the detail-page and kept only the Rating indicator with a binding on value and maxValue... even this reloads the complete list. I think using the Rating Indicator within the list is the issue...

Comment: So have you tried fixing the library to version 1.40.x? Just to test if it's a bug that's been fixed by now?

Comment: <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap-ui-core.js"     id="sap-ui-bootstrap"    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"     data-sap-ui-xx-fakeOS="ios"    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"></script>

Comment: good idea, just tried and same issue. think I Need to open an SAP ticket...